# How do I correctly populate a listbox from an observable collection?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've simplified this just to show what is needed to demonstrate the problem - which is that while 8 items are clearly in the listbox they have no content, i.e. 'Name' does not display, they are just blanks. If I set a breakpoint just after the ItemSource has been set I can see that the the source has been correctly populated with the collection so I assume something must be wrong with my xaml.  Here is the code and xaml:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<ToolboxItem> ToolboxItems;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitToolboxItems();
        lstToolbox.ItemsSource = ToolboxItems;
    }

    private void InitToolboxItems()
    {
        ToolboxItems = new ObservableCollection<ToolboxItem>();

        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item1"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item2"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item3"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item4"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item5"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item6"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item7"));
        ToolboxItems.Add(new ToolboxItem(name: "Item8"));
    }

    public struct ToolboxItem
    {
        public String Name;
        public ToolboxItem(String name) { Name = name; }
    }
}

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ListBox Name="lstToolbox" Width="200" Height="280">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" Height="20" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use implied questions. If you have an actual question, write it out with a question mark.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you bind the ListBox's ItemSource to ToolboxItems vs setting it in code. You'd have to change ToolboxItems to a public property and set (in code) LayoutRoot's DataContext to "this". (I guess this starts going down the MVVM route, which is worth looking into).

Comment: I have added a question mark to my question and inserted the word 'correctly'.  My example was intended to provide context to my question, otherwise how I am trying to populate my listbox could be anyones guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it isn't really a Question (cf. earlier comments), your problem stems from the fact that the Field 'Name' on your ToolBoxItem needs to be a Property to be able to bind to. So change it to:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

and it should work.

Comment: It definitely works, I was just coming back here to say I changed the Name to a property and it worked. I also changed the whole toolbox item struct to a class as well, not sure if that really mattered.

Comment: Yes, it works and as a struct.  I also had to ditch the constructor and populate Name via an initialiser.